# how can I fix this..in select query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

this is a select query...

```
   $q = "SELECT
        tcs.tutor_id AS tid,
        tcs.category_id AS cid,
        tcs.subject_id AS sid,
        GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT s.subjects SEPARATOR ', ') AS subjects,
        t.tutor_name AS tname,
        t.tutor_code AS tcode,
        DATE_FORMAT(t.registration_date, '%b %D, %Y') AS date,
        t.qualification AS qualifi,
        GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT o.option_name SEPARATOR ', ') AS tutor_option,
        timg.image_name AS img,
        city_name AS city,
        d.district_name AS district
   FROM tutor_category_subject as tcs
        INNER JOIN subject AS s ON tcs.subject_id = s.subject_id
        INNER JOIN tutor_option AS toption ON toption.tutor_id = tcs.tutor_id
        INNER JOIN options AS o ON toption.option_id = o.option_id
        INNER JOIN tutors AS t ON tcs.tutor_id = t.tutor_id
        INNER JOIN address ON address.address_id = t.address_id
        INNER JOIN city ON city.city_id = address.city_id
        INNER JOIN district AS d ON d.district_id = city.district_id
        LEFT JOIN tutor_images AS timg ON timg.tutor_id = tcs.tutor_id AND timg.image_type = 'profile'
   WHERE s.subjects LIKE '%$subject%'
   GROUP BY tcs.tutor_id";
```

this query is working now.. now I found a problem. it is..... so many subject may have to one particular tutor. I need to select all the subject that pertaining to a tutor with searching keyword to display with search result. In this query searching keyword is '$subject'.
This query only selecting subjects to the tutor similar to the given keyword. For an example if a user give a keyword like 'business' query selecting subjects to that tutor like 'business studies, business accounting., etc only'. so I need to select other subjects too through this query.. can anybody help me?

thank you.

Comment: Not sure if I got it right but check out `distinct`. Otherwise if you only want subjects with the keyword of one tutor add `&& tutor = id` to get only results for this tutor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I'm not MySQL guru, but I think you don't need to select

```
 tcs.category_id AS cid,
 tcs.subject_id AS sid,
```

and you also need to use `distinct` keyword

```
SELECT distinct
    tcs.tutor_id AS tid,
    GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT s.subjects SEPARATOR ', ') AS subjects,
    t.tutor_name AS tname,
    t.tutor_code AS tcode,
    DATE_FORMAT(t.registration_date, '%b %D, %Y') AS date,
    t.qualification AS qualifi,
    GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT o.option_name SEPARATOR ', ') AS tutor_option,
    timg.image_name AS img,
    city_name AS city,
    d.district_name AS district
FROM tutor_category_subject as tcs
    INNER JOIN subject AS s ON tcs.subject_id = s.subject_id
    INNER JOIN tutor_option AS toption ON toption.tutor_id = tcs.tutor_id
    INNER JOIN options AS o ON toption.option_id = o.option_id
    INNER JOIN tutors AS t ON tcs.tutor_id = t.tutor_id
    INNER JOIN address ON address.address_id = t.address_id
    INNER JOIN city ON city.city_id = address.city_id
    INNER JOIN district AS d ON d.district_id = city.district_id
    LEFT JOIN tutor_images AS timg ON timg.tutor_id = tcs.tutor_id AND timg.image_type = 'profile'
WHERE s.subjects LIKE '%$subject%'
GROUP BY tcs.tutor_id
```